# CLI commands to build (package) .IPA using ionic-v4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am facing issues in generating .IPA using ionic v4 with below command:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --provisioningProfile=“****” --developmentTeam="***" --codeSignIdentity=“iPhone Distribution” --packageType=“enterprise”
```

Its creating .app file inside /Users/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator , but not .ipa

version installed:
ionic : 4.2.1
cordova : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the next checklist:

1. IPAs can be just created using MacOS. Your post doesn't really tell me under which OS you're issuing the command.
2. XCODE is needed. At least until Cordova is compatible with the New Building System.
3. You may try forcing to use the old one by:

   ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --provisioningProfile=“****” --developmentTeam="***" --codeSignIdentity=“iPhone Distribution” --packageType=“enterprise” --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
4. However it has failed for me due the lack of support of Cordova and own XCODE bugs.
5. My recommendation is to issue:

   ionic cordova build ios --prod --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
6. Open the .xcodeproject generated in XCODE.
7. Try using XCODE from that point. You'll find several Pitfalls, most of them answered here.

Hope it helps!